# How to user sum (column) over order by (column desc)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT SUM(E.column1) over (order by E.SrNo) 
as Total from (select row_number over (order by column3) 
as SrNo from table) E;
```

I have a query for question. I am getting this data from Temporary table.

I am using this query with sub query. I got perfect answer when tried on my local database. But I am not able to execute this query on live database.

Can any one help me out?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't start with `select`.

Comment: my question is can use sum with order by clause?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: Ask *another* question with sample data, desired result, and a sensible code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

**SUM(E.column1)** is giving the error. You are calculating this SUM based on a subquery -

```
from (select row_number over (order by column3) as SrNo from table) E
```

So, in the newly created table from subquery, you don't have any column named "Column1". But in the aggregation, you are using it. Add this column at the subquery first and then use it at aggregation.

Comment: i used 
from (select row_number over (order by column3) as SrNo,* from table) E

Comment: "my question is can use sum with order by clause?" - yes, you can. I have been using it for a long time.

Comment: yes i can but i m getting error in live database incorrect syntax near order